# npm permission denied - node-sass

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, npm

I run npm command on Ubuntu and get `permission denied`

```
sudo npm install node-sass

EACCES: permission denied, access '/node_modules/node-sass'
```

I try to run it as a root user or with sudo 
and as global.

The project folder has public(777) access.

> - nodejs version - v10.8.0
> - npm version - 6.3.0

Also, the unsafe package does not solve the problem

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

fixing-npm-permissions don't solve

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: If you haven't read this already, it may help: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: I clean npm cache and rebuild the project

and run `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass`
and now it's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem before, it has to do with your package.lock file and below are the steps which I followed.

- Delete node_modules folder
- Delete your package.lock file or copy it again from your repo.
- Start NPM install again.